# How to restrict access of property and methods to Enum members only?

Tags: python, enums, properties

I have an unorthodox `Enum` that I plan to use in my code, but I've come to a problem where I need my property needed to throw an error when the `Enum` is used incorrectly, however, instead of throwing the Exception, it instead outputted my property's address.

How I want my code to work is:

- When user writes `Enum.MEMBER.text`, return `Enum.MEMBER` alt text.
- When user writes `Enum.text`, throw an error.

Here's the code snippet

```py
class MyEnum(Enum):
    @property
    def text(self):
        if isinstance(self._value_,MyCapsule):  return self._value_.text
        raise Exception('You are not using an Enum!')
        return None

    @property
    def value(self):
        if isinstance(self._value_,MyCapsule):  return self._value_.value
        raise Exception('You are not using an Enum!')
        return None

class MyCapsule:
    def __init__(self,value,text,more_data):
        self._value_, self._text_   = (value,text)
    @property
    def text(self):     return self._text_
    @property
    def value(self):    return self._value_

class CustomData(MyEnum):
    ONE = MyCapsule(1,'One','Lorem')
    TWO = MyCapsule(2,'Two','Ipsum')
    TRI = MyCapsule(3,'Tri','Loipsum')

A = CustomData.ONE
B = CustomData

print(A.text, A.value,sep=' | ')
print(B.text, B.value,sep=' | ')
```

The output is:

```
One | 1
<property object at 0x0000016CA56DF0E8> | <property object at 0x0000016CA56DF278>
```

What I expect was

```
One | 1
Unexpected exception at ....
```

Is there a solution to this problem, or I shouldn't write my `Enum` this way to begin with?

Comment: The main question is why do you need that. Btw, it's not possible.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Basically I plan to use this Enum to "categorize" my data, and use it with my GUI interface. It's kinda hard to explain by words. Honestly this error isn't really a big issue in my code, I just get irritated every time I see a possible error.

Also why is it not possible? I'm thinking if I can check the `cls._value_` type, it should be possible in a way?

Comment: You can't prevent using class name in code, maybe you can achieve it using some "hacks" with different proxies, but i can't identify one single reason to do that.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I don't really have to use class in my code, I can just use tuple or create a custom IntEnum or something, but I would really prefer if I can use class instead of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom descriptor will do the trick:

```
class property_only(object):
    #
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    #
    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is None:
            raise Exception('You are not using an Enum!')
        else:
            return self.func(instance)
    #
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        # raise error or set value here
        pass
```

Then change your base Enum to use it:

```
class MyEnum(Enum):
    @property_only
    def text(self):
        return self._value_.text
    @property_only
    def value(self):
        return self._value_.value

class MyCapsule:
    def __init__(self, value, text, more_data):
        self._value_, self._text_ = (value, text)

class CustomData(MyEnum):
    ONE = MyCapsule(1, 'One', 'Lorem')
    TWO = MyCapsule(2, 'Two', 'Ipsum')
    TRI = MyCapsule(3, 'Tri', 'Loipsum')
```

and in use:

```
>>> CustomData.text
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in __get__
Exception: You are not using an Enum!
```

---

While that solves the "access-only-from-enum" problem, you still have a lot of indirection when you want to access `text` and `value`:

```
>>> CustomData.ONE.value._value_
1

>>> CustomData.ONE.value._text_
'One'
```

The solution is to incorporate `MyCapsule` directly into `CustomData`:

```
from enum import Enum

class property_only(object):
    #
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    #
    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is None:
            raise Exception('You are not using an Enum!')
        else:
            return self.func(instance)
    #
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        # raise error or set value here
        pass

class CustomData(Enum):
    #
    ONE = 1, 'One', 'Lorem'
    TWO = 2, 'Two', 'Ipsum'
    TRI = 3, 'Tri', 'Loipsum'
    #
    def __new__(cls, value, text, more_data):
        member = object.__new__(cls)
        member._value_ = value
        member._text_ = text
        # ignoring more_data for now...
        return member
    #
    @property_only
    def text(self):
        return self._text_
    #
    @property_only
    def value(self):
        return self._value_
```

and in use:

```
>>> CustomData.ONE
<CustomData.ONE: 1>

>>> CustomData.ONE.value
1

>>> CustomData.ONE.text
'One'

>>> CustomData.ONE.name
'ONE'

>>> CustomData.text
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in __get__
Exception: You are not using an Enum!

>>> CustomData.value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in __get__
Exception: You are not using an Enum!
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: This was the thing I was looking for!  It was a big help :)
The indirection part isn't much of a big problem, but it's a nice reference, and somehow I made something similar to it before looking at this answer. lol.
Also I was looking into your `Enum` source code and found another solution, using `DynamicClassAttribute` descriptor. Is this a good idea?
Too bad these aren't recognized as a property by my IDE (VS Code).

Comment: @ZombieChibiXD:  Yes, `DynamicClassAttribute` would also work.